AMM on XRPL create Error - FailtecNO_PERMISSION
I am trying to create AMM pool on XRPL Testnet but I got this error
AMMCreate FailtecNO_PERMISSION, as shown in the transaction bellow
https://testnet.xrpl.org/accounts/r9FAbDFH3bnBaDxGbwo4jKAdpFEQphrGjL/transactions
However, if I used the Devnet its fine,
https://devnet.xrpl.org/accounts/r9FAbDFH3bnBaDxGbwo4jKAdpFEQphrGjL/transactions
Any idea about this issue ?
